# WPF/Xaml Datagrid wont fire ValidatesOnDataErros when binding is in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a datagrid that is bound to an observable collection from my viewmodel.  This all works fine and displays my data in the datagrid.

What i need to do now is validate some columns when the user chnages the text.  I am using the IDataErrorInfo to do this.

If i do the following:-

```
**<TextBox 
     Width="100" 
     Text="{Binding Path=CallCode,
     Mode=TwoWay,
     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>**
```

This works and triggers the validation code in my viewmodel, however if i add this code to the datagrid as below it doesnt do anything!:-

```
<Border x:Name="body"                    
        DockPanel.Dock="Top"   
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.Column="0">

        <!-- Results -->
        <DataGrid x:Name="Results"                            
            ItemsSource="{Binding CallCodesList}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            CanUserAddRows="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns >

            **<DataGridTextColumn                                                     
                     Header="Call Code" 
                     CanUserSort="True" 
                     Width="100" 
                     Binding="{Binding CallCode, 
                     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,  
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged />**

                 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="70"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=HasSpeech}"
                        Header="Speech"
                        IsThreeState="True">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding HasSpeech}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>          
        </DataGrid>
    </Border>
```

Is there someting i am missing or can it not see something because it is in a datagrid, this is all new so currently stuck :(

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: there's no `}"` between PropertyChanged and />.  Is this just from transcribing to SO?

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the code is fine, i don't know if the wpftoolkit's data grid allow IDataErrorInfo validation, but in this article ([Validation in WPF Toolkit’s DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272667/Validation-in-WPF-Toolkit-s-DataGrid)) you can see a good example of using validation on wpftoolkit's data grid, but using the IDataError interface way.
I hope this help to you...

Comment: Thanks for the link, so i pretty much have that and it works when the view is loaded and goes through validation, but still not once the view is loaded and you update a field - Stumped!!!